# libcurl C API > POST ranges of data obtained from URL

Tags: c, url, post, libcurl, chunked-encoding

How can I post ranges of data obtained from URL, not from file? Say I need to read 150-250000 bytes from http://localhost/video.mp4 (A) and POST this data to http://172.32.144.12 (B)  in chunks smoothly so that it looked like the data is streamed from (A) to (B)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply start downloading from A (using a range if you don't want the whole thing) and once you have received enough data to pass it along to site B, you issue a separate request with that data. Meanwhile you continue downloading from A into an alternative buffer etc.

You can do this using two threads or even in the same thread using libcurl's multi interface.